# Click event listener not working on Livewire v3

Tags: laravel-livewire, laravel-10

I have a livewire component where I have shown all users. I want to delete specific user through clicking a button. But it's not working for me. My delete button is not responding. I have attached my component codes in the attachment. Can you help me about this issue?

Thanks...

My Livewire Class Code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Livewire\Users;

use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\User;

class Users extends Component
{
    public $title = 'All Users';

    public $users = null;

    public function delete(User $user) 
    {
        $user->delete();
    }

    public function mount(){
        $this->users = User::all();
    }
    
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.users.users');
    }
}
```

My Component Blade Code:

```
<div>
    <div class="content-header">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row mb-2">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <h1 class="m-0">All User</h1>
                </div><!-- /.col -->
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <ol class="breadcrumb float-sm-right">
                    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="{{ route('dashboard') }}">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="breadcrumb-item active">All Users</li>
                    </ol>
                </div><!-- /.col -->
            </div><!-- /.row -->
        </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.content-header -->

    <!-- Main content -->
    <div class="content">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <h3 class="card-title">Showing all users</h3>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.card-header -->
                    <div class="card-body">
                        @if (session('status'))
                            <div class="alert alert-success">
                                {{ session('status') }}
                            </div>
                        @endif
                        <table id="datatable" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>ID</th>
                                    <th>Name</th>
                                    <th>Email</th>
                                    <th>Added Date</th>
                                    <th>Action</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                @foreach( $users as $user)
                                <tr wire:key="{{ $user->id }}">
                                    <td>{{ $user->id }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $user->name }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $user->email }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $user->created_at }}</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <a href="{{ route('users.update', $user->id) }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-dark">Update</a>
                                        <button wire:click="delete({{$user->id}})" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Delete</button>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                @endforeach
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.card-body -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.card -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.col-md-12 -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.row -->
        </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.content -->
</div>
```

I want to delete specific user using livewire component.

Comment: Any errors in your browser console? Code looks fine to me.

Comment: You're injecting the user model in your delete function. I must say that has never properly functioned for me. I usually just fetch the model manually: `public function delete(int $id) { $user = User::find($id); }` But like Hiighsky mentioned, do you have any browser console errors?

Answer (score 0):

Seems the issue is caused because of you are assigning `Users` data in the `mount()` method.

```php
class Users extends Component
{
    public function delete( User $user )
    {
        $user->delete();
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.users.users', [
            'users' => User::all(),
        ]);
    }
}
```

I verified in my project that the component reloads after the action.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. All are ok from my side. Problem is that, I have used jQuery Datatable plugin. That's why Livewire click event isn't working.